# How many queries do you send to editors a week?

Tags: money, preparation

How often should a writer be sending queries to establish a consistent flow of work?  Currently I have a goal of trying to send out one query a day and at least two a week to places I've never worked with before to try and broaden my portfolio of clips.  Is this enough?

What kind of return can I expect on this level of effort?  What will I need to do in order to up the return on my time investment?

Comment: can you please edit this question to line up with the guidelines presented [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) for StackExchange sites?  Right now it seems to line up with one of the off-topic criteria that “your answer is provided along with the question, in a variant of “I’ll go first”. If you are answering your own question and expecting even more answers to come along, it’s not a real question.”

Comment: Being that this site is not doing as well as it should in terms of daily visits / questions -- why not just edit the question and provide an answer yourself. You've got the rep for it. We need all the questions we can get.

Comment: @Final Draft - in this case I wanted to provide a chance for Kyle to edit the question himself, as well as point out some fairly new guidelines for good questions.  I have tweaked the question myself as suggested - Kyle you can always fix it up if it is not what you meant.

Comment: Is this about fiction or non-fiction? The answers for each will differ quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a query day with no set goals in terms of numbers, other than to send at least one. My day is usually Monday, because that's the most work I can get out myself that day.

If you're asking how frequently you should be sending out queries, the answer is enough to get you enough work. If you're writing for a living, then -- a lot of queries, especially at the beginning when you're taking shorter and lower paying assignments. Later on in your career, when you're landing features that pay upwards of $5,000 or such, you won't need to send as many queries.